# Circularly linked list in Swift

Tags: swift, linked-list

I want to determine whether my linked-list is empty or not, however, I cannot do this by checking head.next==tail because I will get an error that binary operator "==" cannot be applied to operations of type 'LLNode?'.

```
import Foundation

class LLNode<T> {
    var key: T!
    var next: LLNode?
    var previous: LLNode?  
}

public class LinkedList<T: Equatable> {
    private var head: LLNode<T> = LLNode<T>()
    private var tail: LLNode<T> = LLNode<T>()

    init() {
        head.next = tail
        head.previous = tail
        tail.next = head
        tail.previous = head
    }

    func isEmpty() {
        return head.next == tail ? true : false
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It should be func isEmpty() -> Bool

Comment: You need to make `LLNode` conform to the [Equatable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/)

Comment: Just an FYI, the `==` operator gives you a `Bool` value already, so it's completely unnecessary to have ` ? true : false` on the end. In fact any time you see somebody do that, it's always unnecessary, because clearly whatever was on the left of `?` was already a `Bool` value. And if they do it to swap `true` and `false`, they could have just used the `!` operator to flip the value, or used `!=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, you are right. And for the equatable protocol, it is not right for this problem. So I should use === instead of == as Colavitam said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you should probably be checking if `head` and `tail` are the same instance by using the `===` operator. Note that this is different than testing for equality in Swift.

`==` checks for object equality, which you have to define yourself, whereas `===` determines if the two variables refer to the same instance. Your check should therefore look like:

```
func isEmpty() -> Bool {
    return head.next === tail
}
```

The ternary operator is not necessary, as comparison operators already return a Bool.

Comment: And a quick question, is it necessary that the tail in this class? It seems that it doesn't matter if I don't have a tail in the circular linked list.

Comment: By definition, a circularly linked list is a linked list in which the head is the same as the tail. So yes, you are correct; you only need to store it once. In this case, the test would be `head.next === head`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `LLNode` conform to the `Equatable` protocol but this implies that you must constraint `T: Equatable` for all `LLNode` too.

If I were to make minimal changes to your code to make it works, here's how I would it:

```
func isEmpty() -> Bool {
    if let next = head.next where next.key == tail.key {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the contents of the LinkedList were guaranteed to be unique? Comparing the values held by the nodes could lead to incorrect conclusions if the same value is repeated twice.

Comment: My guess is based on the constraint `T: Equatable` and the fact that there's a `key` property in `LLNode`. If the OP meant for it to be used like keys in dictionary then yes, each node must have a unique key